# How to fetch parent and all its children with criteria using Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Parent` and `Child` entities like below -

```
class Parent {
  Long id;
  List<Child> children;
}

class Child {
  Long id;
  String status; // ACTIVE or INACTIVE
  Parent parent;
}
```

I would like to fetch the `parent` along with all its `children` having `status=ACTIVE` property.

```
public interface ParentRepository<Parent, Long> {
     Parent findByIdAndChildStatus(@Param("id") id, @Param("childStatus") status);
    }
```

**Question is** -

1. What is the easiest way to fetch only `ACTIVE` children?
2. Is it possible to set ACTIVE query condition on the `Child` entity's
   `status` property to fetch only active child entities by default?
3. Will something like above query method work?

Answer (score 1):

1. See below
2. It's not possible with Spring annotations alone, but you can achieve it with Hibernate's [@Where](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html):

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Where(clause = "status='ACTIVE'")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

3. Your query method would not work, Spring Data wouldn't understand the method name. To make it work, the `Child` entity would need to be in the plural form:

```
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long> {

    Parent findByIdAndChildrenStatus(Long id, String status);

}
```

Unfortunately, the meaning of the method would be a bit different than expected. It would mean: get Parent with the id `id` and having a Child with the status `status`. The generated query looks as follows:

```
SELECT parent0_.id AS id1_1_
FROM parent parent0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN child children1_ ON parent0_.id=children1_.parent_id
WHERE parent0_.id=? AND children1_.status=?
```